# if-then-else in JSON schema for multiple fields

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

How can I make few fields as "required" based on condition?

For example; in below case if **status**==Failed then i want only four fields as required ("orgId",
            "subunitId",
            "fundOutType",
            "status") 
but any other value of **status** will change the required field list: ("transactionId",
            "orgId",
            "subunitId",
            "fundOutType",
            "fundOutAmount",
            "status")

My below solution is not working. Please help.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "versionId": "1.0",
    "javaInterfaces": [
        "java.io.Serializable"
    ],
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "transactionId": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "orgId": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "subunitId": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "fundOutType": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "fundOutAmount": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "status": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "lang": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "transactionCreatedDateTime": {
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "date-time"
        },
        "userId": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "if": {
        "properties": {
            "status": {
                "const": "Failed"
            }
        },
        "required": [ "status" ]
    },
    "then": {
        "required": [
            "orgId",
            "subunitId",
            "fundOutType",
            "status"
        ]
    },
    "else": {
        "required": [
            "transactionId",
            "orgId",
            "subunitId",
            "fundOutType",
            "fundOutAmount",
            "status"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: What's not working?  I've tried it over on jsonschema.dev, and it appears to be fine.  Can you give an example of an instance that passes that shouldn't or shouldn't pass but is?

Comment: What not working is --> even though status==success and json have 4 fields ("orgId", "subunitId", "fundOutType","status"); validation is passed. It should be failed.

Comment: I'm getting a failure when the instance only has 4 fields and status is anything but "Failed".  Try it here: https://jsonschema.dev/

Comment: Your schema is correct. My guess is that the validator you are using either has a bug or doesn't support draft-07 which is where the `if`/`then`/`else` keywords were introduced.

Comment: What validator library and version you are using, is that support draft-07 schema ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `oneOf` clause instead of the if/else:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "versionId": "1.0",
  "javaInterfaces": [
    "java.io.Serializable"
  ],
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "transactionId": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "orgId": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "subunitId": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "fundOutType": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "fundOutAmount": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "status": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "lang": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "transactionCreatedDateTime": {
      "type": "integer",
      "format": "date-time"
    },
    "userId": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "status": {
          "const": "Failed"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "orgId",
        "subunitId",
        "fundOutType",
        "status"
      ]
    },
    {
      "required": [
        "transactionId",
        "orgId",
        "subunitId",
        "fundOutType",
        "fundOutAmount",
        "status"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

See documentation https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/json-schema-core.html#rfc.section.9.2.1